# formula for getting the cross product in spherical coordinates, given the two vectors.

Tags: vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

I am using this coordinate system:

[image]

consider these two vectors in spherical coordinates:

$$\vec A=A_r \hat r +A_\phi \hat \phi + A_\theta \hat \theta=
A_r\sin{\theta_A} \cos{\phi_A} \hat i 
+A_r\sin{\theta_A} \sin{\phi_A} \hat j
+A_r\cos{\theta_A} \hat k$$
$$\vec B=B_r \hat r +B_\phi \hat \phi + B_\theta \hat \theta=
B_r\sin{\theta_B} \cos{\phi_B} \hat i 
+B_r\sin{\theta_B} \sin{\phi_B} \hat j
+B_r\cos{\theta_B} \hat k$$

In Cartesian coordinates, the formula of the cross product is:

$$\vec A \times \vec B=
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
A_x & A_y & A_z \\
B_x & B_y & B_z \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\hat i & \hat j & \hat k \\
A_r\sin{\theta_A} \cos{\phi_A} & A_r\sin{\theta_A} \sin{\phi_A} & A_r\cos{\theta_A} \\
B_r\sin{\theta_B} \cos{\phi_B} & B_r\sin{\theta_B} \sin{\phi_B} & B_r\cos{\theta_B} \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Which is equal to:

$$
\vec A \times \vec B = (A_yB_z-A_zB_y)\hat i 
+ (A_zB_x-A_xB_z)\hat j 
+ (A_xB_y-A_yB_x)\hat k
$$

What is the formula of cross product in spherical coordinates?

In either form. matrix or in one line.

Comment: **Hint** At each point, $(\hat{r}, \hat{\theta}, \hat{\phi})$ is an oriented orthonormal basis.

Comment: @Travis . ok but what to do with it?

Comment: Dot product of $\vec A\times\vec B$ with $\hat r$ will give you the component along $\hat r$, and so on.

Comment: @Aretino why don't you turn that into an answer? I can't understand!

Comment: @BlueSky In particular, that means that $\hat{r} \times \hat{\theta} = \hat{\phi}$, and likewise for cyclic permutations of the basis. NB that, unlike with Cartesian coordinates, the vectors in this basis change direction from base point to base point!

Comment: @Travis. confused! confused! post  an answer and finish this story!

Comment: I will, but I'd like to know how to target my answer; how much abstract linear algebra do you know? If I write, "Given an oriented $3$-dimensional inner product space over $\Bbb R$, we get a cross product...", is that language useful for you? If that doesn't sound helpful (e.g., you're taking multivariable calc), no worries.

Comment: @Travis. I understood most one your text. except "inner product space"

Comment: I've written an answer, but it occurs to me now that it's more likely that you might want a formula for the cross product of the vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ identified with given points $(r, \theta, \phi)$ and $(r', \theta', \phi')$. In this case, one certainly should *not* be using the notation $\hat{r}$.

Comment: @Travis. yes I want that formula you said.